# pmma vs glass windows?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I was told that PMMA is preferred over glass for windows in cold climates because of it's R-value being higher than glass.I wish there were a stick-on film made of glass! That could be used to cover PMMA windows, to eliminate the "scratch" factor if nothing else.

Comment: All the windows I know about in the Alps, are single (old) double or triple glazed with glass... work fine...

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: A stick-on glass film might be technically possible. Corning's "Willow Glass" might work, if used with an optical adhesive. However, it may well not be economical.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say about the preferences of the whole world. But i live in a what is generally considered to be a cold climate. Atleast here most window panes made out of glass. They simply are not single glass pane. But 3-4 separate pieces of glass separated by air for the outermost layer and possibly inert gas for the second layer. This increases the performance of windows significantly.

The innermost pane is also often laminated with plastic. So in fact the pmma may be sandwitched between glass.

Anyway, i would dispute PMMA is prefered. It is atleast not true in my location. But obviously can vary based on where you are, just that the claim sounds generally nonfactual. There can obviously be other locations like south pole where situation is wastly different.

PMMA can be coated with diamond too by the way, but I havent tested what happens to the coating when the temperatue changes radically.